# How can the JVM get the return value of native methods?

Tags: callback, jvm, java-native-interface, native

Suppose the java method method `A()` calls the native method `read()` to read something. Is `A()` invoked on the same thread as `read()`? 
`A()` is under the JVM's control, but isn't `read()` controlled by the system? 
When `read()` got some data, how can it know that the data was requested by `A()` but not `B()` or `C()`? How can the JVM get the data that was returned by `read()`?

Answer (score 1):

Usually in JVM native calls are performed through JNI in the same thread. In modern JVM, Java threads are implemented as native OS threads. When Java method A calls read(), it may switch from *managed* to *native*, but it behaves just as a normal synchronous function call.